# Is there a way to use selector with createApi to handle custom mapping

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

I am learning **redux** **toolkit** with **react**, I want to do a custom mapping from the response of API to my interface. I created a **slice** using **createApi** function, but I don't know how to do the mapping using **selectors**. Example: the response of API return a json object `{"first_name": "Toto", "last_name": "Foo"}` and my interface is defined with this way:
`interface user { firstname: string, lastname: string }`

In the old way we create a selector with the state as an input and I did a classic mapping field to field.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in `transformResponse` for the endpoint - then it will already be stored in the cache in the right format.

See [Customizing query responses with transformResponse](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#customizing-query-responses-with-transformresponse)

In your case:

```
transformResponse(
  baseQueryReturnValue: unknown,
) {
  return { 
    firstname: (baseQueryReturnValue as any).first_name,
    lastname: (baseQueryReturnValue as any).last_name,
  }
}
```